# Android Auto Certification Requirements

Tags: android, android-auto

As far as I know, Android Auto (My phone streams the screen content to the head unit of the car) needs to be certified in order to be used in a new infotainment system of a vehicle.
Where can I find the certification requirements from google which we need to fulfill?
I got the information, that those can be retrieved from https://docs.partner.android.com/auto using a Google Partner Account.

I'm facing issues here, so I doubt that this information is correct:
In order to register for a Google partner account, you need to have a Google Ads Account [[1]](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9028757?hl=en).
In order to be accepted as a Google partner, this Google Ads account needs to spend at least $10,000 USD in the last 90 days [[2]](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9702452?hl=en) (plus two other requirements, regarding performance and certification).

Furthermore the Google Partner Program Terms and Conditions state at the very beginning [[3]](https://www.google.com/partners/terms/tos)

> Please note: The Google Partners Program, as discussed below, is only available for agencies and third-parties who manage Google Ads accounts for their customers. Individuals or other businesses are not eligible to participate in the Google Partners Program.

The company, I am working for does have a Google Ads account but we are not an agency and therefore do not manage any Google Ads accounts for third parties nor do we spend the required amount...

Can someone share more details about the certification process and the corresponding documents?